# Need numeric sort in views: like 1 2 3 4 not 1 10 11... 19 2 20

Tags: views

I have created view of views or you can say a page of teasers where the teasers are itself views(global views field) and the page is generated as view too. there is a custom field a/c no (in teaser)which I want to sort ascending but it sort like 1 10 11 12 ... 19 2 20... and so on. After using natural view sort it is sorting like 19 53 35 20 54 21 etc, why it is happening and why the natural sort is not working? It does not relate with taxonomy.. I am just wondering that if normal sort is working in view of views then why is not natural sort working to that?

Comment: I think view's uses the field's database tables for sorting. Since you have a view inside another view, it cannot sort it.

Comment: 1 10 11 12 is sorting ascending. So where is the problem since you state you want it sorting ascending?

Comment: yes but I want sorting ascending like 1,2,3,4 but it sort like 1,10,11,.....19,2,20... & so on. It is the problem I am facing in sorting. I need numeric sort & thanks for reply.

Comment: I am also getting the error: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in _views_natural_sort_text_fielad_to_vns() in natural sort module." whenever I add, delete or update anything. Is there not any method to **numeric sort in views** ??

Comment: Views are so important in drupal then they should obviously have this numeric sort facility some how. I really need this to complete my task.

Comment: It's nothing to do with Drupal, it's how MysQL sorts numeric values inside strings. You should have chosen an integer field if you want to sort it as an integer

Comment: thank you so much sir clive! you are right. After changing the field as integer it is working perfectly now.